# Create custom module with javascript .js

Tags: javascript

I want to create a custom module to insert this .js javascript into my joomla site; joomla 3.x version

http://bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js/

how can I do to create my custom text to appear into a module into joomla?

thanks for your help folks!

Comment: What are you asking for here, to inject the Javascript file on to every page or to add custom text to a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this in Joomla:

**1.** You might want to take a look at a plugin called [Sourcerer from NoNumber](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer):

> Sourcerer enables you to place PHP and any kind of HTML style code
> (including CSS and JavaScript) right into your content! Not only in
> your articles, but also in sections, categories, modules, components,
> META tags, etc.

Then you can add javascript directly in the WYSIWYG editor (like TinyMCE), and the plugin will parse the code as needed. Example:

```
{source}
<script src="http://bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js/"></script>
{/source}
```

Other similar extensions can be found here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content

**2.** Another option is to install a custom module from http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules. These are special modules that won't remove your code.

### Edit:

For your specific requirements, I created a very quick n' dirty module to display the MouseFollow demo included in the package. You can find the module here: http://dospuntos.no/extensions/mod_addShine.zip. Simply install it like any other Joomla module and publish it to any page. *(Provided as is, feel free to modify the code if needed).*

Here's the code from the `default.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
* @package    Add Shine.js
* @author     Dos Puntos Design
* @copyright  Copyright (C) 2014 Dos Puntos Design
* @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
**/

// No direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'media/mod_addShine/js/shine.min.js');       // For JS files
$text = $params->get('shine_text');
?>
<style>
.demo-text {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -0.02em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
</style>
    <h1 id="headline" class="demo-text"><?php echo $text ?></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // use new shinejs.Shine(...) if Shine is already defined somewhere else
      // var shine = new shinejs.Shine(document.getElementById('headline'));
      var shine = new Shine(document.getElementById('headline'));
      function handleMouseMove(event) {
        shine.light.position.x = event.clientX;
        shine.light.position.y = event.clientY;
        shine.draw();
      }
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @johanpw, how should I do to insert this javascript http://bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js/ into a module? It also has header /css and /js...

Comment: I want this bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js to be a "banner" in the frontpage of a webpage, but I want it to be a module, so I can choose so where to enable it and where not to.

Comment: Thanks for te job @johanpw... will try it and let you know... thanks a lot for your time and effort.. and for your quick response!

Comment: Hi @johanpw , that was exacly what I wanted to do... question? 1) could you add the second text line in the module, so I can add text like in the example where it says "A library for pretty shadows." in bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js  2) could you teach me how you did the module? if so, how can I get in touch with you?

Comment: @dhacohen I'm glad it worked :) I'll see if I can update the module, but I can't promise anything. Feel free to contact me on Skype: `dospuntosdesign`

Answer (score 4):

I Assume that your current html editor is TinyMCE.

Go to Administrator -> Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> Editor - TinyMCE

Delete the word `script` if it is listed in the "Prohibited Elements" field and save the plugin.

Then create a new "Custom HTML Module" by Going to Administrator -> Extensions -> Module Manager -> <kbd>+New</kbd> -> Custom HTML

Click on the <kbd>Toggle Editor</kbd> and Add the [code](http://bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js/) like this:

```
<style>
    /* In HTML5 you can use style tag inside the body. */
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/shine.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var shine = new Shine(document.getElementById('my-shine-object'));
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        shine.light.position.x = event.clientX;
        shine.light.position.y = event.clientY;
        shine.draw();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Then fill the "Title" field, select the "Position" and enable the module. You can select a desired module assignment as well. Then save it.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Fari, how should I do to insert this javascript http://bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js/ into a module? It also has header /css and /js...

Comment: I want this bigspaceship.github.io/shine.js to be a "banner" in the frontpage of a webpage, but I want it to be a module, so I can choose so where to enable it and where not to.

Comment: I edit my answer. Yes, a Custom HTML module is a module and you can assign it to specific pages.